# curl: Is it possible to set timeout globally in shell

Tags: bash, shell, curl, scripting, config

Is it possible to set timeout value for `curl` globally? E.g. via an environment variable or config file?

I have a shell script with some 20 `curl` commands scattered all over and would like to avoid specifying `--connect-timeout` everywhere.

This is for shell scripting, not php or C/C++ or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

all CLI options can be specified in the 'default config file'

```
# set timeout to 2.5 seconds globally
echo 'connect-timeout = 2.5' > ~/.curlrc
```

---

From [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html): *"When curl is invoked, it (unless -q, --disable is used) checks for a default config file and uses it if found"*.

> ```
> -K, --config <file>
> ```
>
> Specify a text file to read curl arguments from. The command line
> arguments found in the text file will be used as if they were provided
> on the command line.
>
> Options and their parameters must be specified on the same line in the
> file, separated by whitespace, colon, or the equals sign. Long option
> names can optionally be given in the config file without the initial
> double dashes and if so, the colon or equals characters can be used as
> separators. If the option is specified with one or two dashes, there
> can be no colon or equals character between the option and its
> parameter.
>
> If the parameter contains whitespace (or starts with : or =), the
> parameter must be enclosed within quotes. Within double quotes, the
> following escape sequences are available: \, ", \t, \n, \r and \v. A
> backslash preceding any other letter is ignored.
>
> If the first column of a config line is a '#' character, the rest of
> the line will be treated as a comment.
>
> Only write one option per physical line in the config file.
>
> Specify the filename to -K, --config as '-' to make curl read the file
> from stdin.
>
> Note that to be able to specify a URL in the config file, you need to
> specify it using the --url option, and not by simply writing the URL
> on its own line. So, it could look similar to this:
>
> `url = "https://curl.se/docs/"`
>
> ```
>  # --- Example file ---
>  # this is a comment
>  url = "example.com"
>  output = "curlhere.html"
>  user-agent = "superagent/1.0"
>
>  # and fetch another URL too
>  url = "example.com/docs/manpage.html"
>  -O
>  referer = "http://nowhereatall.example.com/"
>  # --- End of example file ---
> ```
>
> When curl is invoked, it (unless -q, --disable is used) checks for a
> default config file and uses it if found, even when -K, --config is
> used. The default config file is checked for in the following places
> in this order:
>
> 1. `$CURL_HOME/.curlrc`
> 2. `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/curlrc` (Added in 7.73.0)
> 3. `$HOME/.curlrc`
> 4. Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\.curlrc`
> 5. Windows: `%APPDATA%\.curlrc`
> 6. Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\.curlrc`
> 7. Non-Windows: use getpwuid to find the home directory
> 8. On Windows, if it finds no .curlrc file in the sequence described
>    above, it checks for one in the same dir the curl executable is
>    placed.
>
> On Windows two filenames are checked per location: .curlrc and
> _curlrc, preferring the former. Older versions on Windows checked for _curlrc only.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see on the [man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), there is no such environment variable.

You could make a function called `curl`:

```
curl () {
    command curl --connect-timeout 60 "$@"
}
```

So whenever you call `curl`, it will call this function, which in turn calls the `curl` command (`command` suppresses shell function lookup) with the same arguments.

Comment: yupp, I also read the man page ! `curl` actually respects `http/https_proxy` env variable, though it's not documented either. I was hoping something similar.

Comment: @Kashyap http_proxy and friends are documented at the link in this answer in the Environment section.